# Gstreamer: OPUS to AAC while RTP to HLS

Tags: node.js, gstreamer

I am trying to record RTP stream with video and audio to HLS. Using GStreamer and nodejs. I get `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "fdkaacenc"`. I am using macOS with M1 CPU and all plugins base, good, bad, and ugly are installed.

The whole command I am trying to execute is this

```
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 -v -e 
rtpbin name=rtpbin latency=50 buffer-mode=0 sdes="application/x-rtp-source-sdes, cname=(string)3xtbiiMIcbTDI1Td" !
udpsrc port=40228 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,payload=(int)105,encoding-name=(string)H264,ssrc=(uint)982701080" 
! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin. ! queue ! rtpvp8depay ! vp8dec ! x264enc ! mux. 
udpsrc port=40401 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio,clock-rate=(int)48000,payload=(int)100,encoding-name=(string)OPUS,ssrc=(uint)906623489" ! 

# the part I am trying to convert opus to aac
rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_1 rtpbin. ! queue ! rtpopusdepay ! opusdec ! fdkaacenc ! mux. 

mpegtsmux name=mux ! hlssink location=storage/recordings/take-3540_question-1996/webcam-029ad85b-7a43-45a5-888f-f5ce873b108f%06d.ts playlist-location=storage/recordings/take-3540_question-1996/webcam-029ad85b-7a43-45a5-888f-f5ce873b108f.m3u8 target-duration=4 
udpsrc address=127.0.0.1 port=40463 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0 rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=23257 bind-address=127.0.0.1 bind-port=40463 sync=false async=false udpsrc address=127.0.0.1 port=40499 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_1 rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_1 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=42134 bind-address=127.0.0.1 bind-port=40499 sync=false async=false
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that by `avenc_aac` instead of `fdkaacenc`. Not to mention that you should use `audioconvert` before avenc_aac.

The part of command I was trying to convert to aac:

`rtpopusdepay ! opusdec ! audioconvert ! avenc_aac`.

**More:** `avenc_aac` is part of gstreamer ffmpeg plugins which exists in linux, mac and windows. `fdkaacenc` is part of gstreamer bad plugins that may not be the same in all systems. That's is why using `avenc_aac` is more approperiate. So it can be executed in both mac and linux.